# Get unique values from list and create check box in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create checkboxes from unique values of list, I am getting all values instead of unique values if i give class name as item name its working fine

Here is my code

```js
var html = '';
$('.bob').each(function() {
  var item = $(this).data('xyz');
  if (!$('input.' + item).length)
    $('.checkboxes').append('<label><input class="testclss"  data-var="' + item + '" type="checkbox" />' + item + '</label>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="dog"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="cat"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>

<div class="checkboxes"></div>
```

Comment: What is the question? Is there PHP to this question?

Comment: You mean you want to have ONE checkbox per animal

Comment: Yes all values are created but i need unique values from the list

Comment: @mplungjan he wants unique value

Comment: Yes I realised....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

check if any check box with any data-var attr exist or not and accordingly generate check box

```js
var html = '';
$('.bob').each(function() { 
    var item = $(this).data('xyz');
    if($("input[data-var='"+item+"']").length == 0)  
        $('.checkboxes').append('<label><input class="testclss"  data-var="' + item + '" type="checkbox" />' + item + '</label>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="dog"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="cat"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>

<div class="checkboxes"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var html = '';
var arr = [];
$('.bob').each(function() {
  var item = $(this).data('xyz');
  if ($.inArray(item, arr) == -1) {//check if value exist in array
    arr.push(item)//add the value in array
  }

});
$.each(arr, function(i, v) {
  $('.checkboxes').append('<label><input class="testclss"  data-var="' + v + '" type="checkbox" />' + v + '</label>');


});
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="dog"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="cat"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>

<div class="checkboxes"></div>
```

1. You can go through the div and add each value in array.
2. Then go through the array and create checkbox base on each value

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your condition `if (!$('input.' + item).length)` is always `true`. Because you're appending a node with class name `testclss` and `$('input.' + item).length` is checking DOM for a `input` node with class name of your item variable.

So just, try appending a node with real classname ie, `item` as follows

```
  var html = '';
$('.bob').each(function() { 
    var item = $(this).data('xyz');
   if (!$('input.' + item).length)
        $('.checkboxes').append('<label><input class="'+item+'"  data-var="' + item + '" type="checkbox" />' + item + '</label>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var html = '';
    var items_arr = [];
    $('.bob').each(function() { 
    var item = $(this).data('xyz');
      if (!$('input.' + item).length)
      {

         items_arr.push(item);
      }
    });

    /*Creating unique array from above*/
    items_arr = items_arr.reverse().filter(function (e, i, items_arr) {
      return items_arr.indexOf(e, i+1) === -1;
    }).reverse();

    /*Then loop items_arr and set your html */  
     Add your code here     
    /**/
```

Comment: just for oder if you want to remove you can

Comment: Why not sort once?

Comment: in case if he wants to use sort for numeric values also,
Since there's no built-in reverse indexof, I reverse the array, filter out duplicates, then re-reverse it.